# Using lat lon slice from NetCDF

Tags: python, netcdf

I am trying to get a subset of data from this NetCDF file that is from the NOAA National Water Model.

Im able to load in the data, read it, and do a basic plot of the entire US. But my goal is to get a slice of just Tuscaloosa County in Alabama. Im looking at the CRS projection and its Lambert_Conformal_Conic and the X Y are in the format like this -1919500.375,  -2303999.17655. The issue is this dataset only has the X Y columns, not a typical latitude and longitude column in the array.

Here is the [data download](https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/nwm/prod/nwm.20221208/medium_range_mem1/nwm.t00z.medium_range.land_1.f003.conus.nc), this [is the data structure](https://www.nco.ncep.noaa.gov/pmb/products/nwm/nwm.t00z.medium_range.land.f003.conus.nc.shtml)

Im not sure how to access the specific location that I want using this type of file. For what its worth, the Tuscaloosa bounding box in lat lon is [-87.840711  33.003379   -87.065738  33.609833]

The code I have so far is:

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import xarray as xr
al = xr.open_dataset("4_AWI_netcdf_test/data/med_range/nwm.t00z.medium_range.land_1.f003.conus.nc")
al_sel = al.FSNO.sel(x=1,y=-0.5, method = 'nearest')
al_sel.plot()
```

Not really if I need to use slice() or sel() and not sure what to include to isolate Tuscaloosa.

Comment: Are you familiar with rioxarray https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/clip_geom.html ?

Comment: project the longlat values to x,y with pyproj, something like this https://gist.github.com/mdsumner/bc39f3053977b8c2aaf1f71e2961c20f

Comment: this is awesome, thank you!!